# POST in Angular 8 is not working for some reason

Tags: angular, api, post

Guys :). I am testing out POST to an API in angular for the first time and it is not working. I looked at others code however it seems without any problem.

Component

```
onSubmit(){
 this.housePostService.addhouse(JSON.stringify(this.addHouseForm.value));
}
```

Service

```
public addhouse(data: string): Observable<string>{
 return this.http.post<string>(this.url, data);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.post()` returns a cold observable. So you should subscribe to the observable to execute it.

Something like this:

```
this.housePostService.addhouse(JSON.stringify(this.addHouseForm.value)).subscribe();
```